# Sklearn OneVsRestClassifier and predict_proba function

Tags: python, python-2.7, scikit-learn

I was going through the sklearn documentation and I read that Onevsrest classifier can be used for multilabel problems also there is a predict_proba function in few of the classifiers that can be used to find the probabilities for fitting a data point against all the labels.

I wanted to understand if I am working on a problem where I need to predict the severity of a fault out of 10 severity types and I can predict all the 10 faults for a given data point from most likely to least likely should I go with Onevsrest classifier or predict_proba function or should I use onevsrest classifier and use the predict_proba function?

Thanks, Jayadeep

Comment: Well, you need to train the `OneVsRestClassifier` in order to call `predict_proba`. You call the `predict_proba` method from the classifier object you instantiated & trained. You can't call the method "outside" the classifier.

Comment: Thanks @RaduGheorghiu

My question is assume I have a requirement where i want to predict the output of a sample from most likely fault to least likely fault should I be using OVR or use any of the classifiers and use predict_proba()

Thanks, Jayadeep

Comment: No, you should use only the `predict` method. That will return the "severity" level, if you have trained your classifier with two appropriate arrays: data & severity_labels

Comment: Hi @RaduGheorghiu, if i understand correctly what you are suggesting is that predict function will return only 1 severity but my requirement is to return all the 10 severities from most likely to least likely. If my understanding is in-correct can you please share a sample snippet so that I can understand